# Audio Normalize in xcode (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, normalization, avplayer

I'm trying to build a music player for iPhone and iPad.
I've used AVFoundation for playback controls. But I'm trying to implement audio normalization as "Sound Check" in "Music" settings in my player, I couldn't find any helpful resource for the same. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: This is not possible.

Expert answer: It is not possible with your chosen frameworks. You need to go down on the lower layer of Core Audio: Audio Units and AudioQueue. But here you will find C code and the need of some signal processing knowledge.

What you can easily do is to change the volume:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error = nil;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

audioPlayer.volume = 0.5; // from 0.0 to 1.0

if(audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             
else 
    [audioPlayer play];
```